# OpenTelemetry 0.83.0 Builder windows 386 reports '' has invalid keys: dist on sample builder-config.yaml

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I am new to OpenTelemetry and I am trying to build a custom collector following the instructions here:
https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/custom-collector/

I am running Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit.  I downloaded otel_0.83.0_windows_386.tar.gz from here:
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-releases/releases/download/v0.83.0/otelcol_0.83.0_windows_386.tar.gz

(I also tried otelcol-contrib_0.83.0_windows_386.tar.gz but it had the same issue).

I used 7-zip to unpack all the files in the tar (LICENSE, otelcol.exe and README.md) into a directory and then created build-config.yaml copied from the custom-collector page:

```
dist:
  name: otelcol-dev
  description: Basic OTel Collector distribution for Developers
  output_path: ./otelcol-dev
  otelcol_version: 0.83.0

exporters:
  - gomod:
      go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/loggingexporter v0.83.0
  - gomod:
      github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/exporter/jaegerexporter
      v0.83.0

processors:
  - gomod:
      go.opentelemetry.io/collector/processor/batchprocessor v0.83.0

receivers:
  - gomod:
      go.opentelemetry.io/collector/receiver/otlpreceiver v0.83.0
```

When I run **.\otelcol.exe --config .\builder-config.yaml** from Windows PowerShell (non-admin) I get the following:

```
Error: failed to get config: cannot unmarshal the configuration: 4 error(s) decoding:

* '' has invalid keys: dist
* 'exporters' expected a map, got 'slice'
* 'processors' expected a map, got 'slice'
* 'receivers' expected a map, got 'slice'
2023/08/16 12:23:42 collector server run finished with error: failed to get config: cannot unmarshal the configuration: 4 error(s) decoding:

* '' has invalid keys: dist
* 'exporters' expected a map, got 'slice'
* 'processors' expected a map, got 'slice'
* 'receivers' expected a map, got 'slice'
```

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?  My ultimate aim is to create a Docker image + Kubernetes with a collector than can send metrics to Azure Insights so if I'm going down the wrong track with a custom collector that would be good to know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to take a different approach and used apk to install OpenTelemetry Collector into a Docker image as described here: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/getting-started/#apk-installation

I didn't work out why I couldn't create a custom collector.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I think you used the wrong binary file. Try downloading the correct one here: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/releases/tag/cmd%2Fbuilder%2Fv0.83.0